# Adding Children with awesome_nested_set in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-sets

How do I add children to a parent using the awesome_nested_set plugin?

I have a model, Unit, which is a nested set. I'd like to add sub-units. Within the edit view, how I let the user add children (sub-units) to the parent (unit)?

Answer (score 2):

I have been implementing something with this gem recently and here's how I approached it:

In the _form partial I used a collection_select with

```
<%= f.collection_select :parent_id, Unit.root.self_and_descendants, :id, :name %>
```

where 'f' is supplied by your form_for and it assumes that Unit has a field 'name' to display in the Select but you can change that as needed.

Answer (score 1):

On one model called Category...
Try:

```
science = Category.where(:name => 'Science')
physics = Category.create!(:name => 'Physics')
physics.move_to_child_of(science)
```

This add category "Physics" to category "Science" i.e.:

```
   ■Science
    ╚ Physics
```